# Search a column for text and highlight that row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for a "/" in a cell within the first column. I need to go through 13 worksheets, find the cell that contains that "/" (which may also contain other text), and highlight that row. Ive been testing out code I've found online and haven't had much luck in getting through the whole workbook.

Dim value As String

```
value = "/"

x = 1

For x = 1 To 13 Step -1
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 1 To lastrow
    Range("a" & i).Find (value)
    Range("a" & i).Rows.Interior.Color = RGB(256, 1, 1)

    Next y
Next x
```

This is the code I'm using. If anyone could offer some assistance I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This can be accomplished with Conditional Formatting based on a formula; e.g. `=ISNUMBER(FIND("/", $A1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's irrelevant to your question, but the first thing I noticed was:

```
For x = 1 To 13 Step -1
```

This will never work; a negative step will only work if the order of the values is descending.

You're missing any selection of a worksheet.  If you are iterating through all worksheets in the workbook, then easiest way to do it is with `For each wks in Worksheets`.

`Find` in Excel VBA is a little convoluted.  A call to `Find` returns the first cell in the range that contains the specified text.  You then need to make subsequent calls to `FindNext` to get any other matching cells.  But, `FindNext` will run forever -- you need to save a reference to the first matched cell, then compare the result you get from `FindNext` until the first matched cell shows up again.

Here's how I would do it:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim value As String: value = "/"
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim firstFound As Range
    Dim nextFound As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        wks.Activate

        Set rSearch = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp))
        Set firstFound = rSearch.Find(value)
        If Not firstFound Is Nothing Then
            Set nextFound = firstFound
            Do
                nextFound.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(256, 1, 1)
                Set nextFound = rSearch.FindNext(nextFound)
            Loop While nextFound.Address <> firstFound.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured that if I used a for statement it would get me through the worksheets. This worked perfectly. Thanks again!